# IUSR can't write to Windows Event Log but Application Pool Identify Can?

Tags: windows, iis, ntfs

I have a website on IIS. The website runs PHP. When an error occurs in PHP, the error should appear in the Windows Event Log (because the `error_log` setting in `php.ini` is set to `syslog`).

If the anonymous user uses the `IUSR` account, the error does not appear in the event log. If the anonymous user uses the `Application Pool Identity` account, the error does appear in the event log.

Why can the `Application Pool Identity` account write to the event log, but the `IUSR` account not? Note that PHP is not writing to a custom source. Also note that the `IUSR` account is in the `IIS_IUSRS` account, which has full access to the Application Source of the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify event log access rights to allow IUSR access to write events in a log.

Check this article for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/set-event-log-security-locally-or-via-group-policy

Comment: I read the article, and I don't get it.

Comment: Actually, I understand it now. So, I need to modify that weird string of text to allow anonymous users to write to the event log. I'm not going to do that, as it's too weird. I'm just going to use the application pool identity.

Comment: So I can't use the application pool identity, because my site needs to access a share in our AD domain, and ACLing each machine to the share is too much work... So i am just not going to use the event log....